# Is there a better way to write this nested if else statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-operator

```
if (restroom) {
  if (fleet) {
    secondIconM9;
  } else {
    secondIcon;
  }
} else {
  if (fleet) {
    firstIconM9;
  } else {
    fistIcon;
  }
}
```

This is the code that I have written. It works and I can refactor it into a ternary but I have a feeling that this is unnecessarily descriptive. Is there a way to better write this nested if-else condition.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't do anything under any circumstances, unless it's in a `with` block which seems unlikely.

Comment: what do you do with the value of `secondIconM9`, for example?

Comment: @Pointy Well, technically it can invoke getters with side effects on `globalThis` — kinda like a `with` block.

Comment: @SebastianSimon yea I guess that's possible

Comment: Related: [Simplify nested if/else with repeated results?](/q/53759675/4642212).

Comment: Opinion based at best. 'unnecessarily descriptive' smacks of premature optimization.

Comment: @Pointy It does work. I didn't post the whole thing because I thought that would be unnecessary. It is used in block to set the styling to a react component

Comment: Well if you're using the flags for styling, you could have the flags correspond to classes that either are or are not present, or "yes-foo" and "no-foo" classes, and then use CSS rules to enforce the styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This keeps things legible and reduces the if/else nesting. That is of course if this code is in a function that returns the icon. Otherwise you'll need the else statement.

```
if (restroom) {
  return (fleet) ? secondIconM9 : secondIcon;
}
return (fleet) ? firstIconM9 : firstIcon;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use else if statements combining each of the true and false combinations.

```
if(restroom && fleet){
   //secondIconM9
}
else if(restroom && !fleet){
  //secondIcon
}
else if(!restroom && fleet){
  //firstIconM9
}
else if(!restroom && !fleet){
  //fistIcon
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to I can see to improve this. The first is longer but a little more readable:

```
if(restroom && fleet) {
  secondIconM9;
}
else if(restroom){
  secondIcon;
}
else if(fleet) {
  firstIconM9;
}
else {
  firstIcon;
}
```

The second is more succinct but perhaps a little less readable:

```
let icon = restroom ? 'secondIcon' : 'firstIcon';
icon += fleet ? 'M9' : '';
```